# Why a ClassCastException but not a compilation error?

Tags: java, inheritance, classcastexception

Why don't I get a compilation error in the code below? I get a `ClassCastException` which is a little confusing. Is it because they are related?

```
class Ink {}

Interface Printable {}
class ColorInk extends Ink implements Printable {}

class BlackInk extends Ink {}


class TwistInTaleCasting {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Printable printable = null;
       BlackInk blackInk = new BlackInk();
       printable = (Printable)blackInk;
   }
}
```

Comment: Compiler does not check explicit casts, but the runtime does. Thus, when running you get the classcastexception.

Comment: This is very basic stuff but IMO doesn't deserve a downvote - the question is clearly articulated, it has enough information to describe the problem and the user posting it needs an answer.

Comment: @Pphoenix: The compiler *does* check explicit casts - it checks that the cast is sensible. (See my answer for an example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm, since neither `BlackInk` nor `Ink` is `Printable`, how (or rather *why*) does the compiler approve the cast?

Comment: @Pphoenix: Again, read my answer - the value of `blackInk` could be a reference to an instance of a class extending `BlackInk` and implementing `Printable`. It compiles for the same reason that `Object o = new Object(); String x = (String) o;` compiles...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why don't I get a compilation error in the code below?

Because the compiler only cares about the static type of the expression you're trying to cast.

Look at these two lines:

```
BlackInk blackInk = new BlackInk();
printable = (Printable)blackInk;
```

*You* know that in the second line, the value `blackInk` only refers to an object of type `BlackInk` due to the first line, but the compiler doesn't. For all the compiler knows (when compiling the second line) it *could* actually have been:

```
BlackInk blackInk = new PrintableBlackInk();
printable = (Printable)blackInk;
```

... where `PrintableBlackInk` is a class extending `BlackInk` and implementing `Printable`. Therefore it's valid (at compile-time) to cast from an expression of type `BlackInk` to `Printable`. If you make `BlackInk` a `final` class, then the compiler knows that there's no *way* that it will work (unless the value is null) and will fail at compile-time, like this:

```
error: inconvertible types
          printable = (Printable)blackInk;
                                 ^
required: Printable
found:    BlackInk
```

The details for this are in [JLS 5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1).

Otherwise, we *have* to wait until execution time to see the failure, because the cast is valid at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

ClassCastException is runtime exception which is why you get to compile your code but get the ClassCastException at runtime.  You can check the javadocs as well - ClassCastException extends the RuntimeException:
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

The reason why you get the ClassCastException is obviously because you are trying to cast an instance of BlackInk to Printable (when you cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance, you will get the ClassCastException at runtime).  In short, when you are casting, you're using type conversion and it needs to be a valid operation else you will get a ClassCastExecption at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The setup will compile properly. However at runtime, since `TwistInTaleCasting` and `Printable` have no relation a class cast exception is thrown. Since ClassCastException is ** notchecked exception** it's alright to not handle any such case in your code.

Comment: OP asked why, You haven't answered.