# ClassCastException but still compiles

Tags: java, casting

A co-worker showed me this code and I know it won't work (In fact, at runtime throws `ClassCastException` when you run it).

I don't know why it compiles, because it cast from 
`java.io.FileInputStream` to `org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource;` none of them implements the same interfaces or extends the same classes in hierarchies.

```java
try (InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("somefile")) {

    InputStreamSource file = (InputStreamSource) fileInputStream;

    // some code

} catch (IOException e) {
    // some code
}
```

Link of respective documentation classes:
[FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)
, [InputStreamSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why a ClassCastException but not a compilation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326534/why-a-classcastexception-but-not-a-compilation-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know why it compiles...

Because it's an explicit cast between a non-`final` reference type and an interface. An explicit cast between reference types says to the compiler: "Look, I (the programmer) know that this cast will be valid at runtime. Trust me." So it does. Later at runtime, of course, since the programmer was *wrong*, it fails.

The compiler doesn't *blindly* trust the programmer, though. Details in [§JLS5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5), but if the compiler can *prove* that it's impossible for the cast to be valid, it'll still reject the cast. It can't do that in your case, though, because `InputStreamSource` is an *interface*, and `FileInputStream` is a non-`final` class. So the `FileInputStream` could well be referring to some subclass object that implements `InputStreamSource`. (Of course, we can tell from looking at it that it isn't, since it was *just* set to the result of `new FileInputStream`. But the compiler doesn't look quite that hard, it only cares about the types involved in the casting.)

Comment: Compiler doesn't always trust the programmer blindly: it won't allow to insert a cast if original class and target class can't be related. For instance, if original class is `final`. Example: if declared `Long var = 1L;`, then `Integer var2 = (Integer) var;` will not compile. It has to be `Integer var2 = (Integer) (Number) var;` (that'll still fail at runtime, ofc).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - Thanks!! I was looking through JLS§5.5 because I thought I remembered there were limits. Fixed, I think.

Comment: So the compiler let you do that because it could be some class that implement the interface. I did some test and it compiles (obviously it fails at runtime). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's an explicit cast. The compiler trusts you that the cast will be valide at runtime, so if it's not the case it fails.